# Как в Laravel тестах проверять хеш значения в БД?

Tags: php, laravel, юнит-тесты, тестирование

В тесте нужно делать проверку **хеш пароля** пользователя в БД.

В **Laravel** есть метод `seeInDatabase`, он проверяет существует ли запись в таблице по массиву ключей-значений. При его помощи не получается сделать проверку поля с хешированым значением, поскольку функция `bcrypt` каждый раз возвращает разные значения.

**Код теста:**

```
public function testResetFinancePasswordAPI()
{
    /** @var array $users */
    $users = $this->seedUsers();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        /** @var \App\Models\User $user */

        $this->be($user);

        $request = [
            'current_finance_password' => $this->financePassword,
            'new_finance_password' => $this->newFinancePassword,
        ];

        $this->post('/lk/settings/reset_finance_password', $request);

        $this->assertResponseOk();
        $this->seeJson();
        $this->seeInDatabase('users', [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'finance_password' => bcrypt($this->newFinancePassword),
        ]);
    }
}
```

P.S. используется версия Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/hashing) видим, Что стандартная авторизация использует Hash фасад, и там есть метод:

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Соответственно нужно сделать `$this-> assertTrue(Hash::check($this->newFinancePassword,$user->password))`, только выборку из базы придется повторить, а то там может лежать кэш

Comment: Спасибо! Буквально за несколько минут до вашего ответа сам додумался так-же сделать. :) Просто предполагал, что возможно в **Laravel** есть какое-то стандартное решение в виде метода типа `assertHash` или что-то подобное... В итоге расширил класс **TestCase** добавил нужный метод с этим функционалом.

Comment: @ragmon Да такое бывает :) долго мучаешься, задаешь вопрос, а потом раз и сам понимаешь как сделать :)